# Problemas con Libreria Room Android

Tags: android, kotlin, room

hace poco quise incorporar una base de datos local y revisando la documentacion de Android me encontre con una libreria llamada Room y a la hora de implementarla a mi proyecto me sale un error, incluso probe con SQLite y tambien tengo problemas, cualquier ayuda lo agradeceria.

El error es el siguiente...

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for com.example.sqliteround2.BBDD.TaskDB. TaskDB_Impl does not exist

Task.kt

```
import androidx.room.Entity

@Entity
data class Task(val nombre:String, val estado:Int)
```

TaskDAO.kt

```
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query
import com.example.sqliteround2.Task

@Dao
interface TaskDAO {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Task")
    fun getTasks():ArrayList<Task>

    @Insert
    fun addTask(task: Task)

}
```

TaskDB.kt

```
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.example.sqliteround2.Task

@Database(entities = [Task::class], version = 1)
abstract class TaskDB: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun taskDAO():TaskDAO

}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.room.Room
import com.example.sqliteround2.BBDD.TaskDB
import com.example.sqliteround2.R
import com.example.sqliteround2.RvAdapter
import com.example.sqliteround2.Task
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object{

        var adaptador: RvAdapter? = null
        var listaTareas:ArrayList<Task>? = null

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val fabAddTask = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fabAddTask)

        val rvTasks = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rvTasks)
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
                applicationContext,
                TaskDB::class.java, "database-name"
        ).build()

        listaTareas = db.taskDAO().getTasks()

        adaptador = listaTareas?.let { RvAdapter(it) }

        rvTasks.setHasFixedSize(true)
        rvTasks.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        rvTasks.adapter = adaptador

        fabAddTask.setOnClickListener {

            startActivity(Intent(this, AddTasks::class.java))

        }

    }

}
```

Gradle

```
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'

    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sqliteround2"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.5"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.5"

}
```

TaskDao_Impl.java

```
import android.database.Cursor;
import androidx.room.EntityInsertionAdapter;
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase;
import androidx.room.RoomSQLiteQuery;
import androidx.room.util.DBUtil;
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteStatement;
import com.example.sqliteround2.Task;
import java.lang.Override;
import java.lang.String;
import java.lang.SuppressWarnings;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "deprecation"})
public final class TaskDAO_Impl implements TaskDAO {
  private final RoomDatabase __db;

  private final EntityInsertionAdapter<Task> __insertionAdapterOfTask;

  public TaskDAO_Impl(RoomDatabase __db) {
    this.__db = __db;
    this.__insertionAdapterOfTask = new EntityInsertionAdapter<Task>(__db) {
      @Override
      public String createQuery() {
        return "INSERT OR ABORT INTO `Task` (`nombre`,`estado`) VALUES (?,?)";
      }

      @Override
      public void bind(SupportSQLiteStatement stmt, Task value) {
        if (value.getNombre() == null) {
          stmt.bindNull(1);
        } else {
          stmt.bindString(1, value.getNombre());
        }
        stmt.bindLong(2, value.getEstado());
      }
    };
  }

  @Override
  public void addTask(final Task task) {
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    __db.beginTransaction();
    try {
      __insertionAdapterOfTask.insert(task);
      __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    } finally {
      __db.endTransaction();
    }
  }

  @Override
  public ArrayList<Task> getTasks() {
    final String _sql = "SELECT * FROM Task";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, _statement, false, null);
    try {
      return _result;
    } finally {
      _cursor.close();
      _statement.release();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: lo unico raro que veo es que tu entity no tiene una primary key. Lee [esto](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#primary-key)

Comment: si es tu primera vez usando Room te recomiendo hacer los codelabs. [Este](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-room-database) es el básico y [este](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin) uno mas avanzado. Ahí esta todo bien explicado

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem ya le agregue la PrimaryKey y aun asi me sale un error

Comment: No pongas -Resuelto-, esto no es un foro!! Marca la respuesta que te ha ayudado como respuesta aceptada y la pregunta quedará automaticamente marcada como resuelta!

Comment: @Dariel la solución no va en la pregunta, para eso dispones de la zona de respuestas, por favor edita y corrige

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error es que estás usando `annotationProcessor` el cual en kotlin debe ser reemplazado por `kapt` y por cierto la última version de Room es 2.2.6.

La implementacion correcta es:

```
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.2.6"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.2.6"
```

Y asegurate de aplicar el plugin kapt al inicio de tu archivo gradle `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

Comment: Ya lo intente e igualmente tengo un error... `Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
   > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)`

Comment: revisaste si tienes el plugin?

Comment: si, ya lo tengo

Comment: No veo ningún otro error. Tal vez es un bug de android estudio. Prueba con Rebuild Project

Comment: ya probe con Rebuild Project y sigo con el mismo error.

Comment: Actualiza el codigo de tu pregunta a ver si puedo encontrar algo. Aunque sigo pensando que es un bug

Comment: Revisando el codigo creo que ya encontre el error, y se ubica en el return del metodo getTasks de la clase TaskDAO_Impl.java

Comment: Pudiste solucionarlo? cual era el mensaje de error?

Comment: Ya arregle el error, gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 1):

Primeramente de acuerdo a el error:

> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot find implementation for
> com.example.sqliteround2.BBDD.TaskDB. TaskDB_Impl does not exist

estas haciendo referencia a una clase `TaskDB_Impl`  que no existe debe ser `TaskDAO_Impl`.

Ahora comentas que obtienes un error en  `return _result;` del siguiente mètodo:

```
 @Override
  public ArrayList<Task> getTasks() {
    final String _sql = "SELECT * FROM Task";
    final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
    __db.assertNotSuspendingTransaction();
    final Cursor _cursor = DBUtil.query(__db, _statement, false, null);
    try {
      return _result;
    } finally {
      _cursor.close();
      _statement.release();
    }
  }
```

En este caso no estas definiendo la variable `_result` y es demasiado importante que este valor sea del tipo `ArrayList<Task>`

Answer (score -1):

El único problema es que has creado la interfaz para Dao, pero no hay ninguna clase que implemente esa interface. Solo tienes que crear una clase TaskDB_Impl e implementar la interfaz TaskDB.

Espero ayudarte. saludos

Comment: En realidad la librería genera las implementaciones automaticamente. Si no lo está haciendo es porque hay algo mal en las anotaciones.

Comment: @SinneroftheSystem ahi estoy mostrando el codigo de mi Gradle, fijate si estoy haciendo algo mal, gracias.

Comment: Esta respuesta no es correcta, pues Room genera las implementaciones en base a las interfaces de manera automática al ejecutarse, tal como menciona @SinneroftheSystem.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn te sugerimos revisar [answer] para responder preguntas en el sitio.